# SQL error: must declare a scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the unique auto-generate key for the last SQL insertion:-

```
INSERT [db].[xyyz] (x,y,z) values (@x,@y,@z)
SET @RowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", y);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z", z);
```

This way, I can access other tables and use the same RowId, to insert data for the current transaction. and hence build the relationship between all tables and a single transaction.

However I get the error:

> Must declare a scalar variable" for the @RowId

I believe somewhere the logical-link between what RowId is and what it means in the SQL table is broken...Can anyone help me fix this?

I am working in C# and not in SQL Server.

**UPDATE**: I cannot get my code to store the `RowID` value in a variable. I have tried:

```
Int32 newRowID = 0;
... SQL QUERY..
...
newRowID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

but I get a null exception error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: It's telling you what the error is; you need to *declare* `@RowId`, unless you've declared it elswehere and just haven't shown it.

Comment: and how do I do that? I had it previously as

int RowId = 0;

Comment: because I am working C# and in asp.net...is that bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Must declare a scalar variable" for the @RowId.

Simply declare it:

```
declare @RowID int;
INSERT [db].[xyyz] (x,y,z) values (@x,@y,@z)
SET @RowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", y);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z", z);
```

Comment: That won't be necessary, because you're already declaring the scalar variable inside your sql.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to access the value, but not yet successful..

Comment: like I want a variable 'rowID' that will store the value retrieved by @RowId.

Comment: Ah ok. Then use SELECT @RowID and use cmd.ExecuteScalar to retrieve the value.

Comment: I tried using :-
Int32 newRowId =0;
.
.
newRowID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();


but I get the error:-

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have this in your script before attempting to set it.

> DECLARE @RowID INT

So your script would be;

```
DECLARE @RowID INT;
INSERT [db].[xyyz] (x,y,z) values (@x,@y,@z)
SET @RowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", y);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@z", z);
```

This is assuming your ID is and Integer field, otherwise set the type accordingly

Comment: thanks Chris. ID is an integer field indeed.